# How to shorten struct declaration with same type attributes in Golang?

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a question about export a module in a package with typing in Golang.

Example, I'd like to export `UserCtrl` in package `controllers`, and package `api` can use `UserCtrl` when import package `controllers`.

Also I want to export `UserCtrl` with **typing**, that means in `api`, I can **call named methods**, example `UserCtrl.findOne()`, or `UserCtrl.findAll()`, not use `map[string]interface{}`.

So I've created new type `UserCtrlType` as struct in Golang

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

// UserCtrlType : Type controller for User
type UserCtrlType struct {
    FindAll           gin.HandlerFunc
    FindOneByID       gin.HandlerFunc
    FindOneByUsername gin.HandlerFunc
}

// UserCtrl : Controller for User
var UserCtrl = UserCtrlType{
    findAll,
    findOneByID,
    findOneByUsername,
}

func findAll(ctx *gin.Context) {

}

func findOneByID(ctx *gin.Context) {

}

func findOneByUsername(ctx *gin.Context) {

}
```

And in package `api`, I import `controller` and use:

```
package api

import (
    Controllers "github.com/huynhsamha/gin-go-app/controllers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var userCtrl = Controllers.UserCtrl

func setUpUserRoutes(router *gin.RouterGroup) {
    router.GET("/", userCtrl.FindAll)
    router.GET("/n/:username", userCtrl.FindOneByUsername)
    router.GET("/d/:id", userCtrl.FindOneByID)
}
```

I'm working with [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin), therefore the struct `UserCtrlType` is repeated many times with type `gin.HandlerFunc`.

Is there any other way to resolve my problem, which can export `UserCtrl` (typed) and reduce repeating type `gin.HandlerFunc` declarations.

When I'm working on Node.JS, I found it is very simple to export modules. Can we simplify this issue in Golang?

Comment: What do you mean with "UserCtrlType is repeated many times with type gin.HandlerFunc"? Do you want "UserCtrl" being a base struct and in api package will "extend" from it?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra, no, I want to export `UserCtrl` with named methods, that mean can use `UserCtrl.findAll()` example. But `UserCtrlType` is repeating multiple times with `gin.HandlerFunc`. Is there any other way to reduce it or use other way for my purpose?

Comment: It doesn't take too much effort, I think you can repeat typing **gin.HandlerFunc**.

Comment: I've found the answer for my problem. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in Go you wouldn't create a structure just to wrap a bunch of function declarations like this; you'd just directly export the functions.

```golang
package controllers
import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
func FindAll(ctx *gin.Context) { ... }
```

```golang
router.GET("/", controllers.FindAll)
```

If you really want to have a struct that contains them as *variable* function references, there is syntax to not repeat the type:

```golang
type UserCtrlType struct {
    FindAll, FindOneByID, FindOneByUsername gin.HandlerFunc
}
```

In general in Go you will probably find this is the least of your repeated code (`if err != nil { return err }` appears a *lot*).  "With typing" isn't a special concept in Go; you can never refer to an object as a map if it isn't one (without going through the `reflect` package, which should be a special case).

Comment: Tnx, your shortening in struct is correct way I'm looking, but your first way, which export function in package `controllers` isn't my needs. I've found my solution for my problem

Comment: Typically in Go you'd write them as methods instead of `func` fields.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer for my problem. I think because of my limited knowledge about Golang, I didn't think of a simpler way for my problem before.

This is my answer for my problem:

```
package controllers

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

// UserCtrl : Controller for User
type UserCtrl struct{}

// FindAll :
func (ctrl UserCtrl) FindAll(ctx *gin.Context) {

}

// FindOneByID :
func (ctrl UserCtrl) FindOneByID(ctx *gin.Context) {

}

// FindOneByUsername :
func (ctrl UserCtrl) FindOneByUsername(ctx *gin.Context) {

}
```

And in package `api`

```
package api

import (
    Controllers "github.com/huynhsamha/gin-go-app/controllers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var userCtrl = Controllers.UserCtrl{}

func setUpUserRoutes(router *gin.RouterGroup) {
    router.GET("/", userCtrl.FindAll)
    router.GET("/n/:username", userCtrl.FindOneByUsername)
    router.GET("/d/:id", userCtrl.FindOneByID)
}
```

I will close this question. Thanks for your attentions.